# How to read local csv file with jquery csv without a file prompt

Tags: jquery, csv, jquery-csv

I want to locally open and handle a .csv file in my browser just like i did with a .xml (getting specific column values).

I got to [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/) and i'm able to use the [Client-Side File Handling example](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/file-handling.html).
Downside is i have to use the "choose file" dialog everytime.
I wanted to cut this step and open the chosen csv automatically.

I believed it was a matter of resolving the `reader.onload` call, wich i assume is waiting for a reload with a chosen file.
After looking at some more examples I copied the function with an onload calling `$( document ).ready( TextData );` as

```
function TextData() {
var file = "export.csv";
// read the file metadata
var output = ''
    output += '<span style="font-weight:bold;">' + escape(file.name) + '</span><br />\n';
    output += ' - FileType: ' + (file.type || 'n/a') + '<br />\n';
    output += ' - FileSize: ' + file.size + ' bytes<br />\n';
    output += ' - LastModified: ' + (file.lastModifiedDate ? file.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a') + '<br />\n';

// read the file contents
printTable(file);

// post the results
$('#list').append(output);

}
```

but it gives me an `undefined` error. (this doesn't read the values yet, but i thought it wasa good starting point to make sure the file was being read)

When i put the choose file dialog back, it works.
Any tips??

Original code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if(isAPIAvailable()) {
      $('#files').bind('change', handleFileSelect);
    }
  });

  function isAPIAvailable() {
    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
      // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
      return true;
    } else {
      // source: File API availability - http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi
      // source: <output> availability - http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/
      document.writeln('The HTML5 APIs used in this form are only available in the following browsers:<br />');
      // 6.0 File API & 13.0 <output>
      document.writeln(' - Google Chrome: 13.0 or later<br />');
      // 3.6 File API & 6.0 <output>
      document.writeln(' - Mozilla Firefox: 6.0 or later<br />');
      // 10.0 File API & 10.0 <output>
      document.writeln(' - Internet Explorer: Not supported (partial support expected in 10.0)<br />');
      // ? File API & 5.1 <output>
      document.writeln(' - Safari: Not supported<br />');
      // ? File API & 9.2 <output>
      document.writeln(' - Opera: Not supported');
      return false;
    }
  }

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var file = files[0];

    // read the file metadata
    var output = ''
        output += '<span style="font-weight:bold;">' + escape(file.name) + '</span><br />\n';
        output += ' - FileType: ' + (file.type || 'n/a') + '<br />\n';
        output += ' - FileSize: ' + file.size + ' bytes<br />\n';
        output += ' - LastModified: ' + (file.lastModifiedDate ? file.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a') + '<br />\n';

    // read the file contents
    printTable(file);

    // post the results
    $('#list').append(output);
  }

  function printTable(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function(event){
      var csv = event.target.result;
      var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
      var html = '';
      for(var row in data) {
        html += '<tr>\r\n';
        for(var item in data[row]) {
          html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
        }
        html += '</tr>\r\n';
      }
      $('#contents').html(html);
    };
    reader.onerror = function(){ alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName); };
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id=inputs class=clearfix>
  <input type=file id=files name=files[] multiple />
</div>
<hr />
<output id=list>
</output>
<hr />
<table id=contents style="width:100%; height:400px;" border>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use html5 feature readfile()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=file]").change(function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
      var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

      var csv = document.createElement("p");
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        csv.html = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      console.log(csv);
      $("input[type=file]").after(csv);
    }
  });
});
```

In this example your csv file will be loaded and attached to html document. For editing this file on client-side you may configure 'csv' variable.